# numpy: apply operation to multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Assume I have a matrix of matrices, which is an order-4 tensor. What's the best way to apply the same operation to all the submatrices, similar to Map in Mathematica?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pylab import *
t=random( (8,8,4,4) )
#t2=my_map(det,t)
#then shape(t2) becomes (8,8)
```

**EDIT**
Sorry for the bad English, since it's not my native one.

I tried `numpy.linalg.det`, but it doesn't seem to cope well with 3D or 4D tensors:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.rand(8,8,4,4)
>>> np.linalg.det(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1703, in det
sign, logdet = slogdet(a)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1645, in slogdet
_assertRank2(a)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 155, in _assertRank2
'two-dimensional' % len(a.shape))
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 4-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

**EDIT2 (Solved)**
The problem is older numpy version (<1.8) doesn't support inner loop in `numpy.linalg.det`, updating to numpy 1.8 solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy 1.8 has some gufunc that can do this in C loop:

for example, `numpy.linalg.det()` is a gufunc:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(8,8,4,4)
np.linalg.det(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I got error message:   numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 4-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional

Comment: Are you using numpy 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

First check the documentation for the operation that you intend to use.  Many have a way of specifying which axis to operate on (`np.sum`).  Others specify which axes they use (e.g. `np.dot`).

For `np.linalg.det` the documentation includes:

> a : (..., M, M) array_like
>       Input array to compute determinants for.

So `np.linalg.det(t)` returns an `(8,8)` array, having calculated each `det` using the last 2 dimensions.

While it is possible to iterate on dimensions (the first is the default), it is better to write a function that makes use of `numpy` operations that use the whole array.